# Как изменить Python конфигурацию?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь использовать subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'pyinstaller']), в собраном exe, на другом пк без питона.

Ошибка:

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\AdminVM\\Desktop\\\u04511\u0451\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\AdminVM\\Desktop\\\u04511\u0451\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\AdminVM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI24682\\python310.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\AdminVM\\Desktop\\\u04511\u0451',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

1. **print(sys.path)** - выдаёт как раз другие и нужные пути, но как мы видим в ошибке иначе.
2. Вообще с чего там **python.exe** и **python.zip**?
3. Все модули в Temp, находятся в архиве base_library.zip в том числе и модуль **encodings**, который в основном и вызывает ошибку. И да, как я выше говорил, **print(sys.path)**, выдаёт как я думаю, нужные пути и как раз к base_library.zip

И вот как мне быть? Как поменять пути? Стоит ли вообще их менять? Или вообще есть иначе решение?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148108/discussion-on-question-by-romchik---python-); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.